# Creating an image with text using Perl's Image::Magick

Tags: perl, imagemagick, cgi

I am working on some examples for a lunch-n-learn talking about HTTP context headers and some of the things they are used for.  I figured to add some flare into things, to create an image with Perl's Image::Magick.

Thanks to a comment on this original post I have learned the problem is a missing Content-Length.  How do I get the correct context length from the image?

P.S. I tweaked the Content-Type to make type capital.

```
#!/perl/bin/perl.exe

use Image::Magick;

$image = Image::Magick->new;
$image->Set(size=>'100x100');
$image->ReadImage('canvas:white');
$image->Set('pixel[49,49]'=>'red');

$text = 'Works like magick!';
$image->Annotate(font=>'kai.ttf', pointsize=>40, fill=>'green', text=>$text);

print "Content-Type: image/png\n\n";
binmode STDOUT;
$image->Write('png:-');
```

Comment: You need Content-Length header. And Content-Type, with capital letter

Answer (score 2):

Why not Mojolicious ([An amazing real-time web framework](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Tutorial))?

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

use Image::Magick;

get '/' => sub {
  my $c = shift;

  ...

  $c->render( data => $image->ImageToBlob( magick => 'png' ), format => 'png' );
};

app->start;
```

run it with `perl my_script.pl daemon`

And open in browser localhost:3000

Or fix for original code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Image::Magick;

my $image = Image::Magick->new;
$image->Set( size => '200x200' );
$image->ReadImage( 'canvas:white' );
$image->Set( 'pixel[49,49]' => 'red' );

$image->Annotate(
    font      => 'kai.ttf',
    pointsize => 22,
    fill      => 'green',
    text      => 'Works like magick!',
    gravity   => 'northwest',
);

my $img_size;
my $img_data = $image->ImageToBlob( magick => 'png' );

{
    use bytes;
    $img_size = length $img_data;
}

binmode STDOUT;
print <<EOD;
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: $img_size

$img_data
EOD
```

Comment: This is also a complete CGI script, if you add a shebang, rename it `.cgi` and point Apache at it correctly.

Comment: I highly modified my original post. Forgive me, but I am not a Perl expert, I opted for Perl over C because I figured that it would be easier to setup an Apache/Perl environment in a zip file to distribute to folks.  This is all to say, while I am sure you have a great response, I don't even begin to understand it:) . Considering there is no mention of HTTP Headers, which is the whole point of the example, I am thinking it is a no-go.  All the same, I would like to understand it better.  Can you point to a blog that explains whats going on with the Mojolicious::Lite, it looks very interesting.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code, but it isn't working.  I am getting a "Use of uninitialized value $img_data in concatenation".  It looks like the assignment in the curly brackets are not working correctly.  I tried removing them and adding a no bytes after it, same error.  I don't know Perl well enough to know how to do away use bytes; and put that inline.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I have also done some exploring of $image->ImageToBlob, looks like it returns a void*.  I am stumped on how to get the length of it.  When I removed the whole Content-Length to see what happened I got this: **Use of uninitialized value $img_data in concatenation (.) or string**

Comment: ImageToBlob() must return binary data, then we try to get length of that data. Play around with ImageToBlob(), try different image format. My source works fine on my home and work linux machines

Comment: k-mx, One of the things that I find very frustrating about all these great open source tools is that many don't work real well on Windows.  I think this is yet another case of that :(